# Oracle date of previous year

Tags: oracle, date, datetime

I have the following values in 1 column in Oracle:

```
20123103
20113112
20103006
```

The data type is varchar.

I need to go back 1 year and find the dates in the same format in Oracle.

So, the output should be:

```
20123103 -> 20110104
20113112 -> 20110101
20103006 -> 20090107
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert it to a date, subtract a year, and then format it back to a string:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(date_column, 'YYYYDDMM') 
                - INTERVAL '1' YEAR
                + INTERVAL '1' DAY, 
               'YYYYDDMM')
FROM   my_table
```

Comment: given the sample output, I think the query also needs to add a day: `... - INTERVAL '1' YEAR + INTERVAL '1' DAY...`.

Comment: It also gives error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: @dang had an extra `)` there by mistake - fixed.

Comment: EDIT: Added the one day interval as per comments by @dang and Ed Gibbs